# crossDomain jquery ajax not getting json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, cross-domain

I simply created a rails 3.0 scaffold and exposed it using json, and kept it running.

So if I hit http://localhost:3001/objects.json

I see json data in browser

Next I have one plain html which includes code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js. I opened this page in firefox(ubuntu), then opened the firebug console and tried following

```
var myurl = 'http://localhost:3001/objects.json';

$.ajax({
url: myurl,
dataType: 'jsonp',
error: function(data){ console.log("error:"+data); console.log("error:"+data.readyState); },
success: function(data){ console.log("success:"+data); }
});
```

I wanted to fetch same json here in success handler, what I have observed so far is

if specified dataType: 'jsonp'

1. I do get json response(checked with firebug:Net), same as I see in browser
2. I do not get success called
3. I do get error called, with status code = 4, and status  = "success"

else I get

response blank

And one more thing, every time I get 200 back.

Any hints ...whats going on here?

Adding my server side code and log

code =>

```
# GET /objects
# GET /objects.json
def index
  @objects = Object.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json  {
      render :json => @objects.to_json, :layout => nil
      }
  end
end
```

log sample =>

```
Started GET "/objects.json?callback=jQuery17024293556233345082_1321347517236&_=1321347853199" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-11-15 14:34:13 +0530
  Processing by objectsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"callback"=>"jQuery17024293556233345082_1321347517236",     "_"=>"1321347853199"}
  [1m[35mobject Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT `objects`.* FROM `objects`
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Comment: my doubt is the json I am receiving may not be correct json. Ok then how could I say that accept it as txt and give me that, any jquery setting for that?

Comment: what about `dataType: json` ?

Comment: anything other than dataType: 'jsonp', I get response blank (if I check with firebug Net window)

Comment: jsonp can't return error-codes, so there is something wrong here.

Comment: this is just GET, I have to make PUT/POST ahead :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you using `$.getJSON` may be better

Comment: same result :( var myurl = 'localhost:3001/objects.json?callback=?';; $.getJSON(myurl, function(data){alert(data);}); This handles success calls only. alert wont work here.

Comment: you need not using jsonp,just json,$.getJSON support cross domain to get json. or will you using your broswer to test your url localhost:3001/objects.json. whether the url works

Comment: yes, browser url works http://localhost:3001/objects.json returns expected json, and when I use (jsonp with $.ajax) or (url+'?callback=?' with $getJSON), they both seem same, I do get 200, and json data, but somehow success wont get called

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you returning result in the wrong `Content-type` (not jsonp). If you want jQuery to fire 'success' event regardless the `Content-type`, remove `dataType` parameter from ajax options

Comment: if I remove dataType, I get status as "error" with blank response

Comment: Oh, I guess that your JS script is not on the same domain as objects.json ? You wanna make sure that you're using some kind of jQuery crossDomain workaround.

Comment: jQuery does not support crossDomain requests out-of-the-box. You may look here: https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax

Answer (score 0):

First,  I am guessing it should be `Object.all`

I am assuming that the server your requesting from is different from the server that provides you with JSON data. i.e. different ports in this case or I see no need to use JSONP.

JSONP is not ajax but uses the src attributes in the script tags. If your trying to access information from the same server it `dataType: json` should be the approach.

If you are fetching information from a different server i suggest you add to the end of your url stream a `?callback=?`.

With Jquery $.getJSON should be the way to go. For example

`$.getJSON(url, data, function(response){

// Do something with response;
        });`

Reference http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

In reference to your last comment use this format.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "cat",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){});

  });
```

**Update**
Just remembered this bit, If you have control over both servers are you sending JSONP responses? If this is your JSON data

```
response = { status:'success', message:'Successfully created object'}
```

To send it as JSONP you must wrap it up in a function(). Like

```
jsoncallback + "(" + JSON.stringify(response)  + ");";
```

What this does is it executes the function generated by Jquery (this is done internally when specifiy callback=?. You can get the value by checking localhost:3001 logs) and passes your JSON data as parameters to that.

So if on the server side you are not generating JSON-P response it wont work.

Comment: Adding the ?callback=? to the url automatically makes it a jsonp request. Sorry did not read the title correctly the first time

Comment: yes, corrected Object.all, 2nd its corss domain. tried getJSON with callback? which is similar to JSONP, no success, it has success handler which wont work. Seems I do get data, however frontend engine fails to parse it

Comment: try setting the dataType to 'json' instead of 'jsonp'

Comment: Do we need any server side settings to allow cross-domain calls?

Answer (score -1):

We ran into a similar issue once long back, although with json, not jsonp. And it wasn't a cross-domain problem. Counting on my memory, I believe we had to remove respond_to from the controller and provide :status => 200 to render method to get it working. I'm not very sure, but you could give it a shot.